# Vim's command to create a new file with the same content of any other file

Tags: vim

Say, there is a file **first.txt** and I want to make a new file **second.txt** with the same content of **first.txt**, is there a direct command in Vim to do that?

I don't want to first create **second.txt** and then copy the content of **first.txt**.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, in my opinion O'reilly series, learning vi editor, sed&awk and mastering regular expressions, these books are fantastic. But I need to read 'bash script' books to integrate all the information built in a sense. 'Linux and the Unix Philosophy by Mike Gancarz' helps this a lot.

Comment: There's an online game called [VIM Adventures](https://vim-adventures.com/). It seems quite nice, it's free for the first couple of levels. I never tried it myself, but I've seen a few good reviews about it

Comment: Note there's also https://vi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Regarding learning the basics of Vim, you can use the vimtutor. You can get to it through the command prompt for Ubuntu, you can just type, `vimtutor`, and this is a short 30 minute set of lessons to learn the basics of Vim.

Answer (score 15):

Just open `first.txt` and run the command:

```
:w second.txt
```

Comment: will you please suggest me any book or kind of to learn,i am using Ubuntu from last 3-4 month and found don't learn any thing.

Comment: @atharvamishra Go step by step. For vim, you can just start with the command `vimtutor`, as the name indicates, it's a tutor for vim, in vim. For linux... is too broad to point to something particular. Start with basic commands in the terminal, using the man pages and/or the help: `man <command>` or `<command> --help`. You can refer also to [https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/).

Answer (score 3):

Although [the straightforward simple answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1218603/192564) has already been posted, I offer a fun and instructive alternative:

```
:!cp "%" second.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @Warren Young to suggest me another good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, open the first file, then do `:saveas second.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

open new file

```
:o newfile.txt
```

read from old file:

```
:r oldfile.txt
```